# How can you add custom attributes to a python function object within the function declaration?

Tags: python

I'm looking to create a richly annotated codebase. I remembered functions in Python are objects, therefore they allow arbitrary attributes. For example:

```
def foo(x:int, y:int)->int:
    '''This is a doc string'''
    return x**2 + y**2

foo.__notes__ = {
    'Dependencies':['x', 'y']
}

foo.__notes__

>>> {'Dependencies': ['x', 'y']}
```

I'm looking to set the `__notes__` attribute from within the function definition. Any ideas on how this could be achieved?

---

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, `__notes__` is a poor name for this attribute. `_notes` is more appropriate.

Comment: Nothing in the definition is evaluated until you actually call the function (and then it is evaluated *every* time you call the function).

Comment: Richly annotated, but for what audience?  Not for other programmers, because for that purpose we have comments #.  Not for automatic documentation generators, because for that purpose we have docstrings and the standard pydoc module.  What properties of the available tools do you find inadequate?

Comment: @PaulCornelius To be fair, the doc string is just a way to set a string-valued `__doc__` attribute on the function. You might want more richly typed attributes as well.

Comment: @PaulCornelius - I admit part of it is sheer curiosity to see if it can be done. I intend to use it to power tooltips, aliases, map data dependencies, assumptions on missing values, etc.  I could use "bigger" data structures for it (eg. custom classes) but figured this might be fun to try something new. I have a few things in the `__doc__` string now and I extract them via regex - this is looking to replace that. Moreover I can embed non-string objects, like small pandas DataFrames as examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a decorator to attached the annotation after the function is defined.

```
def add_note(k, v):
    def _(f):
        if not hasattr(f, '_notes'):
            f._notes = {}
        f._notes[k] = v
        return f
    return _


@add_note('Dependencies', ['x', 'y'])
def foo(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x**2 + y**2
```

As an aside, dunder names (like `__notes__`) are reserved for the implementation; you should not invent your own. Just use an ordinary "private" name prefixed with a single `_`.

Comment: This looks very clean, thank you. Can you think of a way of adding objects declared inside the function to the `_notes` attribute?

Comment: Nothing I would recommend using. I assume you want them added *before* you execute the function the first time, even if you are OK with them being re-added every time the function is called. The only way to do that would be introspect the source code itself, which I think would really be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Yes, on balance I agree. I'll go ahead with your decorator.

Comment: I find your use of underscores a little strange. Could you explain? ie. why you are doing `def _(f):` or `return _` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer somewhat differently.  A function can refer to its own name in its body and can assign/read values to whatever it finds.

In your case, assuming you want to introspect what a function does, what you want to do is to drive function behavior from what's decorated on its object.

Note that in my example below `adder3` - which does what you want and updates *from within the function body* is not documented from the POV of an introspection tool *until it has been executed at least once*.

`adder2` on the other hand is set up so that it adjusts its behavior according to its annotation *and that annotation* is visible to introspection tools at all times.

`adder4` is added to show one limit of this approach.  Referring to the function's name is **not** a guarantee that you are in fact accessing the function, *only whatever the function name resolves to in the globals*.

```
def adder1(x:int = 1, y: int = 2, z: int =3 )->int:
    '''This is a doc string'''
    return x**2 + y**2

def decorate(**kwds):
    """ assign kwds as attributes to the function object """
    def actual_decorator(func):
        for k, v in kwds.items():
            setattr(func, k, v)
        return func
    return actual_decorator

depends = {"x","y"}
@decorate(_note=f"depends:{depends}", depends=depends)
def adder2(x:int = 1, y: int = 2, z: int =3 )->int:
    # a function can totally refer to its name 
    # and use annotations to dynamically adjust its behavior
    depends = adder2.depends
    #sum up dependencies
    li = []
    for key in depends:
        v = locals()[key] ** 2
        li.append(v)

    return sum(li)        

def adder3(x:int = 1, y: int = 2, z: int =3 )->int:
    """ no note until function execution so this won't allow tools to inspect the module"""
    _note = getattr(adder3,"_note",None)
    if not _note:
        adder3._note = "depends x,y"
    return x**2 + y**2

def adder4(x:int = 1, y: int = 2, z: int =3 )->int:
    """there is no guarantee that referring by its own name works"""
    print("\n\nadder4.name:", adder4.__name__)
    return (x**2 + y**2) * 1000

adder4_saved = adder4
#swap name
adder4 = adder2 

for func in [adder1,adder2,adder3,adder4_saved]:
    print(f"\n{func.__name__} [note(before)={getattr(func,'_note',None)}] -> {func()} [note(after)={getattr(func,'_note',None)}]")
```

#### output:

```
adder1 [note(before)=None] -> 5 [note(after)=None]

adder2 [note(before)=depends:{'y', 'x'}] -> 5 [note(after)=depends:{'y', 'x'}]
adder3 [note(before)=None] -> 5 [note(after)=depends x,y]


adder4.name: adder2

adder4 [note(before)=None] -> 5000 [note(after)=None]
```